# Edit and Save multiple rows together Mat-table angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10, mat-table

Currently in my application, we have a mat-table angular 10 which allows the user to add one new row into
the table.
The next requirement is to allow the users to edit data in multiple rows and multiple columns and then allow them to save the data on a single button click.
The row should become editable on click of a checkbox in the first cell of that row.
Is it possible to edit and save data from  multiple rows together. Appreciate any ideas on how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: create a FormArray, you show the value or an input according the value of the checkBox

Comment: Yes possible using reactive form groups

Comment: thanks, i ll do some research, do you know of any examples that i could see?